# Drop rows by index with date index

Tags: python, pandas

I need to delete the rows of a dataframe in a certain period of time, in this case my index is time, but i can't

[image: My dataframe]

i try:

```
df.drop(df.loc['2021-01-27 00:34:00':'2021-03-12 20:43:00'])
```

but the code interprets that the second term is a column

Comment: Hey welcome to StackOverflow! Please post a minimal version of your data in a way people can work with it. Also, it looks like your attempt is missing a closing bracket!

Comment: Thanks, my data is that of the image, only a dataframe with dates in the index

Comment: df.drop(df.loc["2017-01-02":"2017-01-05"].index) works!!! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) here:

`df.query("Fecha < '2021-01-27 00:34:00' | Fecha > '2021-03-12 20:43:00'")`

Comment: Thanks but, I think that "query" does not work for the index

Comment: `query` also works for indices.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.drop(df.loc["2017-01-02":"2017-01-05"].index)
```

Works.